# @DynamicInsert is not working when parent class have this annotation but not child

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a parent class

```
@MappedSuperClass
@DynamicInsert
class Parent{
@Column(name = "created_at")
private Timestamp createdAt;

}
```

Child class -

```
@Entity
class Child extends Parent{
@Column(name="prp")
private int someProperty;
}
```

Now when i am calling save operation on child entity object then it is not ignoring created at field in insert query. As it is null so dynamic insert should ignore it. Am i doing something wrong or it is the default behaviour. Please help.

Using Spring Data JPA

Comment: It is desired behaviour. Java does not have or support annotation inherited to child class if applied on parent so we have to apply it on child.